# An outside site seems to have crawled, scraped, and translated Stack Exchange questions; what to do?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

I was curious how often I'd used a couple of idiosyncratic terms in my answers, so I googled them together and was surprised to see them on an external site, having survived a translation into Spanish.

[Original answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125892/how-can-a-gm-challenge-players-with-high-stats)

[External site](http://www.jugonestop.com/pregunta/83123/como-puede-un-gm-desafiar-jugadores-con-stats-alto)

The site appears to have translated portions of arqade.se and rpg.se. As someone who only speaks one language; that is, an American, I have no idea if their attribution or operation is in keeping with Stack Exchange fair-use guidelines. I was hoping someone more conversant could take a look around.

Comment: Each page lists the author, and links back to their account on SE.

Comment: @Servy looks like only arqade there. The page I linked attributes my answer to a low-rep user on arqade who... might have my rpg.se user number?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I saw that, but my problem is that I can't understand the site enough to make a coherent report.